# PHP not to redirect after MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, redirect

I have a form that saves some data in a MySQL table, and after doing it, the website is redirecting to the index.php page, which I don't want to occur, I just want it to stay in the same page.

I have some ajax passing the form values:

```
      $("#incomeSave").click(function() {

      alert("incomeSave");

    $.ajax({

      type:"POST",
      url: "actions.php?action=incomeSave",
      data: "date=" + $("#incomeDate").val() + "&value=" + $("#incomeValue").val() + "&category=" + $("#incomeCategory").val() + "&subcategory=" + $("#incomeSubCategory").val() + "&account=" + $("#incomeAccount").val() + "&description=" + $("#incomeDescription").val(),

      success: function(result) {

      alert(result);

      } 

    })

  })
```

Then the query is executed:

```
    if ($_GET['action'] == "incomeSave") {

    if (!$_POST['value']) {

        echo "Valor vazio";

    } else {

            mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO incomes (`user_id`,`income_date`,`income_value`,`income_category`,`income_subcategory`,`income_account`,`income_description`) VALUES ('1','". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['date'])."','". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['value'])."','". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['category'])."','". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['subcategory'])."','". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['account'])."','". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description'])."')");

            echo "After SQL";

    }

}
```

What should I do so the page is not redirected to the index.php?

Comment: Are you sure the data is getting saved in the database?

Comment: Hey Ronald, yes the query is running just fine fortunately!

Comment: Some ajax guru's will probably confirm but i think you are missing something like 'preventDefault' or return false in the javsacript portion of your code. That will prevent the 'reload on click' to append.

Comment: Check if the <button></button> is present over which your ajax event is working. If yes change the button type='button'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `<form>` tag in your HTML, any `<button>` or `<input type="button">` will trigger a reload automatically. To prevent this from happening, you need to pass an `element` parameter and call the `.preventDefault()` method. Here's what you should do using `e` as the parameter:

```
$("#incomeSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("incomeSave");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "actions.php?action=incomeSave",
        data: "date=" + $("#incomeDate").val() + "&value=" + $("#incomeValue").val() + "&category=" + $("#incomeCategory").val() + "&subcategory=" + $("#incomeSubCategory").val() + "&account=" + $("#incomeAccount").val() + "&description=" + $("#incomeDescription").val(),
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, your database is open to SQL injection, use parameterized statements!

Comment: This worked just fine! Thanks a lot Zeke! Also thanks for the SQL tip, I have been programming for just a few months as a hobby so I did not know about it, I will definitely read about it and implement! All the best!

Comment: I'm glad. Please refer to this question to learn about parameterized statements and a whole lot more too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 Happy coding!